# Submit value from HTML form to Node-js using post request

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I want to submit input value from **HTML** form to **Node.js**
we have the following files:

1. app.js
2. index

output: console.log(“post request made”);

What should I do?

```js
    const express = require('express')
    const app = express()
    
    const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
      extended: true
    }))
    // app.use(express.urlencoded({
    //   extended: true
    // }))
    
    app.post('/submit-form', (req, res) => {
      const username = req.body.username
      console.log('HASAN');
      res.end();
    })
```

```html
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <form method="POST" action="/submit-form">
        <input type="text" name="username" />
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: See the duplicate i have added below @Hasan. That will help you print the console.log() in the browser.

Comment: Should work, but on the browser side you wouldn't see anything, ie a blank page would show as you didn't send anything back to the client. You would only get a console log of `HASAN` on the server. You will need to actually include a problem statement to your question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to process POST data in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295782/how-to-process-post-data-in-node-js)

Comment: You are not sending anything to client so it is showing blank page. Add  ```res.send('<h5>form received</h5>)``` before res.end().

Comment: you can console.log req.body to see what response you got from client.

Comment: _"output: `console.log(“post request made”);`"_ If you want to log a message client side you would need to use some `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch` request to do that as using a default form request changes the page's location to the action url